# Javascript in Assets not working after Rendering Partial in js.erb Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Question similar to mine are asked before but here the scenario is bit different - I have a `js.erb` file in which I'm publishing using (`private_pub`) a partial like below

```
<% publish_to "/conversation/update_waiter" do %>
   $("#online_waiters").replace_html('<%= j(render :partial => "/restaurants/online_waiters")%>');     
<% end %>
```

the partial is rendered on all users wall successfully and no extra or duplicate `div`s are generated . But on `click` function (which is an `anchor` in newly rendered partial) stops working . While its functionality is defined in /assets/js . Now after showing that partial on users if i refresh the page , then the same partial which is displayed due to my cookies , works fine . Any help or idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attach the click handler to a parent element of the generated elements and it will work on all generated elements from partials.

Say you have a `div` with class `content` which contains all your html.

```
$(".content").on("click", "#anchor_one", function(e) {
  console.log("Working!");
});
```

Or attach it to the `document`

```
$(document).on("click", "#anchor_one", function(e) {
  console.log("Working!");
});
```

Another solution is to add the handler inside your `js.erb` file.

Comment: Today i realize that Backend development without core JS knowledge brings you down . thanks man it helped